# Api Platform - Use a specific search filter for a specific path

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

For the same entity, I created 2 different path for inbound and outbound links in my example. In the documentation (Swagger) I want to use as filter only **href** for inbound and **page** for outbound. For the moment, all fields appear for the 2 paths.
I'm on Symfony 4.4 and Api Platform 2.4.
Thanks for your help.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     shortName="page_links",
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "inbound"={
 *              "path"="/page/links/inbound",
 *              "method"="GET",
 *          },
 *          "outbound"={
 *              "path"="/page/links/outbound",
 *              "method"="GET",
 *          }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={"get"={"method"="GET", "path"="/page/links/{id}"}},
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"href": "partial", "uid": "partial", "page": "partial"})
 * @ORM\Table("res_link_pages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ResLinkPagesRepository")
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding some openapi_context attributes

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     shortName="page_links",
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "inbound"={
 *              "path"="/page/links/inbound",
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "openapi_context" = {
 *                  "parameters" = {
 *                      {
 *                          "name" = "page",
 *                          "type" = "string",
 *                          "in" = "query"
 *                      }
 *                  }
 *              }
 *          },
 *          "outbound"={
 *              "path"="/page/links/outbound",
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "openapi_context" = {
 *                  "parameters" = {
 *                      {
 *                          "name" = "href",
 *                          "type" = "string",
 *                          "in" = "query"
 *                      }
 *                  }
 *              }
 *          }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={"get"={"method"="GET", "path"="/page/links/{id}"}},
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"href": "partial", "uid": "partial", "page": "partial"})
 * @ORM\Table("res_link_pages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ResLinkPagesRepository")
 */
```